# Container for threads process isolation

Tags: containers, kernel, lxc, chroot, isolation

I want to know if is possible to customize an LXC kernel (or relation system like OpenVZ, etc) to work just for threads process, see this mention:

> Unlike Docker, Virtuozzo, and LXC, which operate on the process level,
>   LVE is able to operate on the thread level. This allows multithreaded
>   servers such as Apache (with its 'worker' MPM) to take advantage of
>   LVE without having to run a separate instance per LVE user.

source:
blog.phusion.nl/2016/02/03/lve-an-alternative-container-technology-to-docker-and-virtuozzolxc/